# how to solve the summation

Tags: summation

This question might have been asked before but I have not been able to find it.

How can I find:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n 2^{x-i}$$

Help?

Comment: Hint: $2^{x-1} = 2^x/2^i$.

Comment: (1) Figure out/understand the answer when $x=0$; (2) notice that you can factor $2^x$ out of the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{k} = \frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$
to obtain
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{2^{k}} = 2 - \frac{1}{2^{n}}.$$
This leads to
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{2^{m}}{2^{k}} = 2^{m+1} - \frac{2^{m}}{2^{n}}.$$

If $m=n$ then 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^{n-k} = 2^{n+1} - 1.$$